# Can PHP SimpleXML be used for this task?

Tags: php, parsing, loops, simplexml, nodes

I'm looking to run some kind of loop on some optional XML data.

Nodes would potentially look like this:

```
<link1>
 <url>http://www.bleh.com</url>
 <text>Click here</text>
</link1>
<link2>
 <url>bleh.com</url>
 <text>Click here</text>
</link2>
```

What would be the best method to determine if these nodes exist and parse them accordingly?

Comment: A valid XML document requires a root element, so I strongly suggest to wrap the links into a root element `<links>`. Also do not use `<link1>`, `<link2>` and so on, but `<link id='1'>` or just `<link>`. The numbering is implicit. Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560827/php-simplexml-check-if-a-child-exist and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129241/php-using-simplexml-to-loop-through-all-levels-of-an-xml-file

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SimpleXML, then you can simply use isset() to determine whether a node exists.

Comment: But then how would I loop through subsequent nodes link1, link2, etc?

Comment: With a for loop? Although I should mention that naming all elements `<link/>` would be a much wiser choice.