# How to access custom XML elements via SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xml-namespaces

How can I access custom XML elements via SimpleXML. So if I have:

```
<rss>
   <custom:element></custom:element>
</rss>
```

Right now these elements are simply being ignored when I pass them into `simplexml_load_string()`.

Comment: Search for "simplexml namespaces" and you should find numerous examples.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to add a string to this before you'll get a result. E.g.

```
<?php
$xml = "<rss>
        <custom:element>hello world</custom:element>
    </rss>";
$result = simplexml_load_string($xml);
print_r($result);
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Comment: Also check out http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302

Comment: Yes, I've done that.  print_r doesn't show `custom:element`

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'm not completely sure about this, other than to say you could try and loop through every element (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129241/php-using-simplexml-to-loop-through-all-levels-of-an-xml-file) and add the namespace there. The gotcha is that I just tried this and it doesn't work as intuitively as I might have hoped. If you look at http://uk.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getdocnamespaces.php there is an example of getting the namespace, and it looks like you'd want to get the key from this result as you loop through. I'll keep trying tomorrow.

Comment: This helped me. Not completely custom, but shows how to load in namespace: https://www.sitepoint.com/parsing-xml-with-simplexml/